# WebRTC setup and related queries

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to setup a peer to peer connection for WebRTC application. I have read the forums and discussion groups which lead me to the point that STUN/TURN servers are required for the same. Here are the details:

1. I downloaded  the open source implementation of the STUN/TURN server from https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/
2. Installed the server on my local Mac OS X machine and turned on the server on localhost:3478
3. When I tested the server using the client scripts, I was able to get back the remote address from the server.
4. However, when I try to hit the server from my JavaScript code while creating a peer to peer connection, it is not hitting the server itself.

Below is the code which I am using :

```
function createPeerConnection() {
     var pc_config = {'iceServers': [{'url':'turn:127.0.0.1:3478', 'credential':'Apple123'}]};
       try {
        // Create an RTCPeerConnection via the polyfill (adapter.js).
        pc = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(pc_config);
        pc.onicecandidate = gotLocalCandidate;
        trace("Created RTCPeerConnnection with config:\n" + "  \"" +JSON.stringify(pc_config) + "\".");
      } catch (e) {
        trace("Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: " + e.message);
        alert("Cannot create RTCPeerConnection object; WebRTC is not supported by this browser.");
          return;
      }

      pc.onconnecting = onSessionConnecting;
      pc.onopen = onSessionOpened;
      pc.onaddstream = onRemoteStreamAdded;
      pc.onremovestream = onRemoteStreamRemoved;        
}
```

Appreciate any guidance in this matter as I am completely stuck at this point. 
One more question: How to setup a peer to peer connection for WebRTC application where both peer A and B are present on an internal network? Is STUN/TURN servers required then?

Answer (score 0):

First, TURN servers are something that are used only if failing to setup an p2p connection directly. About 86% of all calls can be made without relaying via a TURN server (according to [this](http://io13webrtc.appspot.com/#51) slide, which I by the way recomend to get a better understanding of TURN (from slide 44)).

TURN server should be outside your network since the purpose of it is to relay the stream when not possible to do so in other way.

I would recomend you to start with the case where both A and B are on the same network. Then you do not need to worry about using STUN/TURN. It's enough complicated as it is.

Comment: Thnaks for a quick reply. I am trying to setup a peer to peer connection on the same network. Can you throw some light on how to proceed with this or direct me to a link? Because, I have tried creating a local and remote peer connection on the same machine which worked perfectly fine. However while creating a peer to peer connection on different machines I am facing the problem of getting the IP address of the other machine thru the code.

Comment: It sounds like you have gotten to the point that you need to figure out how to get the messages through to the other node. For this, I use node.js and websockets but the choise is free. But you need some sort of server function that is able to relay the messages to the right peer.

Comment: Just an update.. I was able to setup a WebRTC connection sucessfully on an internal network. Now I am proceeding ahead for establishing the same on a VPN. I guess here is where TURN/STUN servers enter the scene. Am I right??